# Access query to grab +5 or more duplicates

Tags: sql, database, ms-access-2007

i have a little problem with an Access query ( dont ask me why but i cannot use a true SGBD but Access )
i have a huge table with like 920k records
i have to loop through all those data and grab the ref that occur more than 5 time on the same date

table = myTable

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
| id  |      ref            |      date     |   C_ERR_ANO    |
--------------------------------------------|-----------------
| 1   |    A12345678        |   2012/02/24  |    A 4565      |
| 2   |    D52245708        |   2011/05/02  |    E 5246      |
| ... |    .........        |   ..../../..  |    . ....      |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

so to resume it a bit, i have like 900000+ records
there is duplicates on the SAME DATE ( oh by the way there is another collumn i forgot to add that have C_ERR_ANO as name)

so i have to loop through all those row, grab each ref based on date AND errorNumber

and if there is MORE than 5 time with the same errorNumber i have to grab them and display it in the result

i ended up using this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Centre.REFERENCE, Centre.DATESE, Centre.C_ERR_ANO
FROM Centre INNER JOIN (SELECT 
    Centre.[REFERENCE],
    COUNT(*) AS `toto`,
    Centre.DATESE
    FROM Centre
       GROUP BY REFERENCE
       HAVING COUNT(*) > 5)  AS Centre_1 
       ON Centre.REFERENCE = Centre_1.REFERENCE
       AND Centre.DATESE <> Centre_1.DATESE;
```

but this query isent good
i tried then

```
SELECT DATESE, REFERENCE, C_ERR_ANO, COUNT(REFERENCE) AS TOTAL
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM Centre
    WHERE (((Centre.[REFERENCE]) NOT IN (SELECT [REFERENCE] 
        FROM [Centre] AS Tmp 
            GROUP BY [REFERENCE],[DATESE],[C_ERR_ANO]
            HAVING Count(*)>1  AND [DATESE] = [Centre].[DATESE] 
            AND [C_ERR_ANO] = [Centre].[C_ERR_ANO] 
            AND [LIBELLE] = [Centre].[LIBELLE])))
        ORDER BY Centre.[REFERENCE], Centre.[DATESE], Centre.[C_ERR_ANO]) 

    GROUP BY REFERENCE, DATESE, C_ERR_ANO
```

still , not working

i'm struggeling

Comment: Does the reference number or the error code repeat for a given date?  Do you want 5+ of the same error or the same reference or do all 3 have to match 5+ times (Date, Ref, ErrNo)?

Answer (score 0):

Your group by clause needs to include all of the items in your select.  Why not use:

> select Centre.DATESE, Centre.C_ERR_ANO, Count (*)
>
> Group by Centre.DATESE, Centre.C_ERR_ANO
> HAVING COUNT (*) > 5

If you need other fields then you can add them, as long as you ensure the same fields appear in the select as the group by.

No idea what is going on with the formatting here!

Comment: i'll test your tips and come back asap :) Andrew, thx for help dude :)

Comment: edit: i already did that and it return to me the data for the same date BUT, i think the trick could be to group by on the DATESE and from that result i have to get the result > 5

lets say for the date 2012/02/23 i have like 3 redundant reference,
i need to grab the unique reference ( distinct reference ) and group by date based on the c_err_ano

because a reference could have multiple c_err_ano
so group by reference on the date based on c_err_ano 
and from the result of that group by grab everything above 5 result

Comment: The way to think of it with the group clause is that in order for you to get >1 in count then the data needs to be identical.  If, you have (for the sake of argument) date of 24/09/2013, error of 12 and you have 6 of those then grouping on the 2 fields will return 6.  If you had an extra field, such as distinct reference then you will get 6 results, each with a count of 1 which is not what you are wanting.